# Trying add a function on a web based sistem with JS but error 404, cant find it

Tags: javascript, function, addition

im trying add this

javascript:(function () { $('').attr('src', '../proximocod.js'+Date.now()).appendTo('body'); })();

to a web based system, but the console writes

VM1598:1 GET http://192.168.1.240:97/inspire/proximocod.js1507296640033?_=1507296640034 404 (Not Found)

VM1598:1 XHR failed loading: GET "http://192.168.1.240:97/inspire/proximocod.js1507296640033?_=1507296640034".

Ive noticed that Date.now() are diferent but idk how to fix it.

Thanks for all info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the Date.now() to the Filepath. You need to add an questionmark in front of it. 
Than you will get:
http://192.168.1.240:97/inspire/proximocod.js?_=1507296640034

If your serverfile got the timestamp within his path, you should not do it. You will only have one millisecond the same time at your frontend and server.

```js
(function () { 
  $('').attr('src', '../proximocod.js?_='+Date.now()).appendTo('body'); 
})();
```

Comment: Worked, now i need to solve the js code. Thanks a lot